# Need a suggestion on curve processing (curve-fitting, interpolation)

Tags: optimization, interpolation, curve-fitting

I have a set of points which form some curve, see picture. This curve consists of straight and curved sections and I do not know exactly where they start or end. In the presented picture I know at least five pieces: two straight sections, one section with a constant radius, two other types of curves. I want to be able to recognise those sections, to separate them from each other and to work with them as with separate curves.

Update.

In my opinion splines would not work in the way I want, and not surely Besier. I was thinking about Non-linear Least Squares but was not sure if it suits this case. If I am able to separate the parts, then I can use Linear Least Squares for straights and some non-linear for other parts. Otherwise, I need some universal method which will work for all types of curves: 1, 2 and 3 power.

Please share your thoughts.
Thank you.
[image: the curve]

Comment: May I ask what process/model/data created this curve ?

Comment: @ThorstenS. this I created myself from several sets of measurements. This is a centre line of a bent tube. The points I calculated from the scanned surface of the tube. Due to the error of the scan and computations, the points deviate from the real centre line, and I cannot work with them in normal way.

Answer (score 0):

For a bent tube I would suggest multidimensional spline fitting. Your tube does not look like a composition of of straight and curved sections, but curves smoothly all the way.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

This is the starting point if you want to read further.
Taking a guess I suppose you are not experienced with splines, so if you could put out the dataset in table form me or some other reader could interpolate the given data with a 3D spline curve.

Comment: The tube, actually has straight parts, although it does not look like that. I have some experience with splines, and I do not want to use them, since I get then non-straight pieces where they should be straight. Do you have other ideas?